# Why does my derivative function produce strange results?

Tags: c, floating-point, calculus

I am writing a small calculus library for personal use. In it are the standard calculus tools - taking the first derivative, nth derivative, Riemann sums, etc. One problem I have faced is that the nth derivative function is returning patently bogus results for certain values of h (the finite difference).

[Code here](http://pastebin.com/6ttezSde) and below:

```
typedef double(*math_func)(double x);
inline double max ( double a, double b ) { return a > b ? a : b; }

//Uses the five-point-stencil algorithm.
double derivative(math_func f,double x){
    double h=max(sqrt(DBL_EPSILON)*x,1e-8);
    return ((-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h));
}

#define NDEPS (value)
double nthDerivative(math_func f, double x, int N){
    if(N<0) return NAN; //bogus value of N
    if(N==0) return f(x);
    if(N==1) return derivative(f,x);
    double* vals=calloc(2*N+9,sizeof(double)); //buffer region around the real values
    if(vals==NULL){ //oops! no memory
        return NAN;
    }
    int i,j;
    //don't take too small a finite difference
    double h=max(sqrt(DBL_EPSILON)*x,NDEPS);
    for(i=-(N+4);i<=N+4;i++){
        vals[i+N+4]=derivative(f,x+h*i);
    }
    //for(i=0;i<2*N+9;i++){printf("%.1e ",vals[i]);}putchar('\n');
    for(j=1;j<N;j++){
        double *vals2=calloc(2*N+9,sizeof(double));
        for(i=2;i<2*N+7;i++){
            vals2[i]=(-vals[i+2]+8*vals[i+1]-8*vals[i-1]+vals[i-2])/(12*h);
        }
        free(vals);
        vals=vals2;
        //for(i=0;i<2*N+9;i++){printf("%.1e ",vals[i]);}putchar('\n');
    }
    double result=vals[N+4];
    free(vals);
    return result;
}
```

A sample problem I give to test this function is the 5th derivative of sin(x) when x=pi. As we all know, the answer is -1. The problem comes when I try to vary the value of NDEPS ("Nth derivative epsilon").

- When NDEPS=1.5625e-2 (1/64.0): 5th derivative of sin() at x=pi:-1.0003e+00 (looks fine though).
- When NDEPS=1e-5 (1/100000.0): 5th derivative of sin() at x=pi:2.4302e+11 (I'm calling bullshit here).

Why does this happen? Is it related to the nature of the sin() function? Or is it because of floating-point accuracy issues?

Comment: Probably a floating point accuracy issue.

Comment: Though I can't open your line (blocked by my FW), I strongly suspect it is because of accuracy.

Comment: Since we can't see your 'perfectly fine derivative' function, we can't easily tell what's going wrong.  We have to guess that it is something to do with floating point precision.  I suppose we can use `double derivative(math_func fun, double x) { return cos(x); }` to work with this specific test case, but we shouldn't have to guess how you've written the code.  Please review how to write an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have edited the question to include the definition of `derivative()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of your code.  The main modification, apart from using more white space, is to make `NDEPS` into an argument to the `nthDerivative()` function, so that it can be called with different values and to add copious printing.  I've also had to get inventive on the plain `derivative()` function; the code compiles correctly (but I'm really not trying to make a philosophical or theological statements with the assertion `assert(sin == fun);`, but it does mean the code compiles without warnings and it recognizes the limitations of this derivative function).

#### Code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max(a, b)    (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

#define PRIe_double    "%21.15e"

typedef double(*math_func)(double x);

static double derivative(math_func fun, double x) { assert(sin == fun); return cos(x); }

static double nthDerivative(math_func f, double x, int N, double NDEPS)
{
    if (N < 0) return NAN; //bogus value of N
    if (N == 0) return f(x);
    if (N == 1) return derivative(f, x);

    double* vals = calloc(2*N+9, sizeof(double)); //buffer region around the real values
    if (vals == NULL) //oops! no memory
        return NAN;

    int i, j;
    //don't take too small a finite difference

    double h = max(sqrt(DBL_EPSILON)*x, NDEPS);
    printf("h = " PRIe_double "\n", h);

    for (i = -(N+4); i <= N+4; i++)
    {
        vals[i+N+4] = derivative(f, x+h*i);
        printf("%2d: deriv(" PRIe_double ") = " PRIe_double "\n", i, x+h*i, vals[i+N+4]);
    }

    for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf("Iteration %d\n", j);
        double *vals2 = calloc(2*N+9, sizeof(double));
        for (i = 2; i < 2*N+7; i++){
            vals2[i] = (-vals[i+2] + 8*vals[i+1] - 8*vals[i-1] + vals[i-2]) / (12*h);
        }
        free(vals);
        vals = vals2;
        for (i = 0; i < 2*N+9; i++)
            printf("%2d: " PRIe_double "\n", i, vals[i]);
    }
    double result = vals[N+4];
    free(vals);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    double val = M_PI;
    double eps;
    double r;

    eps = 1.0 / 64.0;
    r = nthDerivative(sin, val, 5, eps);
    printf("5th Derivative of sin(x) at x = " PRIe_double " = " PRIe_double " (eps = %f)\n", val, r, eps);

    eps = 1.0 / 100000.0;
    r = nthDerivative(sin, val, 5, eps);
    printf("5th Derivative of sin(x) at x = " PRIe_double " = " PRIe_double " (eps = %f)\n", val, r, eps);

    return(0);
}
```

#### Output

Using GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5, the output is:

```
h = 1.562500000000000e-02
-9: deriv(3.000967653589793e+00) = -9.901285883701071e-01
-8: deriv(3.016592653589793e+00) = -9.921976672293290e-01
-7: deriv(3.032217653589793e+00) = -9.940245152582091e-01
-6: deriv(3.047842653589793e+00) = -9.956086864580017e-01
-5: deriv(3.063467653589793e+00) = -9.969497940760287e-01
-4: deriv(3.079092653589793e+00) = -9.980475107000991e-01
-3: deriv(3.094717653589793e+00) = -9.989015683384429e-01
-2: deriv(3.110342653589793e+00) = -9.995117584851364e-01
-1: deriv(3.125967653589793e+00) = -9.998779321710066e-01
 0: deriv(3.141592653589793e+00) = -1.000000000000000e+00
 1: deriv(3.157217653589793e+00) = -9.998779321710066e-01
 2: deriv(3.172842653589793e+00) = -9.995117584851364e-01
 3: deriv(3.188467653589793e+00) = -9.989015683384429e-01
 4: deriv(3.204092653589793e+00) = -9.980475107000991e-01
 5: deriv(3.219717653589793e+00) = -9.969497940760287e-01
 6: deriv(3.235342653589793e+00) = -9.956086864580017e-01
 7: deriv(3.250967653589793e+00) = -9.940245152582091e-01
 8: deriv(3.266592653589793e+00) = -9.921976672293291e-01
 9: deriv(3.282217653589793e+00) = -9.901285883701071e-01
Iteration 1
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: -1.091570566584531e-01
 3: -9.361273104952932e-02
 4: -7.804555123490846e-02
 5: -6.245931771829009e-02
 6: -4.685783565504131e-02
 7: -3.124491392324735e-02
 8: -1.562436419383969e-02
 9: -1.776356839400250e-15
10: 1.562436419384087e-02
11: 3.124491392324558e-02
12: 4.685783565504250e-02
13: 6.245931771828653e-02
14: 7.804555123490846e-02
15: 9.361273104953050e-02
16: 1.091570566584471e-01
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
Iteration 2
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: -3.577900251527073e+00
 3: 1.660540592568783e+00
 4: 9.969497901146779e-01
 5: 9.980475067341610e-01
 6: 9.989015643694564e-01
 7: 9.995117545137316e-01
 8: 9.998779281977730e-01
 9: 9.999999960264082e-01
10: 9.998779281978486e-01
11: 9.995117545137319e-01
12: 9.989015643693869e-01
13: 9.980475067340947e-01
14: 9.969497901149178e-01
15: 1.660540592568512e+00
16: -3.577900251527123e+00
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
Iteration 3
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: 6.553266640232313e+01
 3: 1.898706817407991e+02
 4: -5.267598134705870e+01
 5: 3.608762837830827e+00
 6: 4.685783548517186e-02
 7: 3.124491378285654e-02
 8: 1.562436412277357e-02
 9: 3.226456139297321e-12
10: -1.562436412279785e-02
11: -3.124491378869069e-02
12: -4.685783548888563e-02
13: -3.608762837816180e+00
14: 5.267598134704988e+01
15: -1.898706817408119e+02
16: -6.553266640231030e+01
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
Iteration 4
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: 8.382087654791743e+03
 3: -5.062815705775390e+03
 4: -7.597917560836845e+03
 5: 3.261984801532626e+03
 6: -4.336626618856812e+02
 7: 1.791410702361821e+01
 8: -9.998779233550453e-01
 9: -9.999999914294619e-01
10: -9.998779238596159e-01
11: 1.791410702341709e+01
12: -4.336626618847606e+02
13: 3.261984801532444e+03
14: -7.597917560838102e+03
15: -5.062815705774387e+03
16: 8.382087654792240e+03
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
5th Derivative of sin(x) at x = 3.141592653589793e+00 = -9.999999914294619e-01 (eps = 0.015625)
h = 1.000000000000000e-05
-9: deriv(3.141502653589793e+00) = -9.999999959500000e-01
-8: deriv(3.141512653589793e+00) = -9.999999968000000e-01
-7: deriv(3.141522653589793e+00) = -9.999999975500000e-01
-6: deriv(3.141532653589793e+00) = -9.999999982000000e-01
-5: deriv(3.141542653589793e+00) = -9.999999987500000e-01
-4: deriv(3.141552653589793e+00) = -9.999999992000000e-01
-3: deriv(3.141562653589793e+00) = -9.999999995500000e-01
-2: deriv(3.141572653589793e+00) = -9.999999998000000e-01
-1: deriv(3.141582653589793e+00) = -9.999999999500000e-01
 0: deriv(3.141592653589793e+00) = -1.000000000000000e+00
 1: deriv(3.141602653589793e+00) = -9.999999999500000e-01
 2: deriv(3.141612653589793e+00) = -9.999999998000000e-01
 3: deriv(3.141622653589793e+00) = -9.999999995500000e-01
 4: deriv(3.141632653589793e+00) = -9.999999992000000e-01
 5: deriv(3.141642653589793e+00) = -9.999999987500000e-01
 6: deriv(3.141652653589793e+00) = -9.999999982000000e-01
 7: deriv(3.141662653589793e+00) = -9.999999975500000e-01
 8: deriv(3.141672653589793e+00) = -9.999999968000000e-01
 9: deriv(3.141682653589793e+00) = -9.999999959500000e-01
Iteration 1
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: -7.000000116589669e-05
 3: -5.999999941330713e-05
 4: -5.000000598739025e-05
 5: -3.999999683331386e-05
 6: -2.999999600591015e-05
 7: -2.000000257999327e-05
 8: -1.000000082740371e-05
 9: 0.000000000000000e+00
10: 1.000000082740371e-05
11: 2.000000165480742e-05
12: 2.999999508072429e-05
13: 3.999999590812801e-05
14: 5.000000413701854e-05
15: 5.999999663774957e-05
16: 6.999999746515327e-05
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
Iteration 2
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: -3.583333244325556e+00
 3: 1.666666318844711e+00
 4: 1.000000128999663e+00
 5: 1.000000691821058e+00
 6: 9.999995738881511e-01
 7: 9.999997049561470e-01
 8: 1.000000198388602e+00
 9: 1.000000075030488e+00
10: 1.000000144419428e+00
11: 9.999996509869722e-01
12: 9.999995893079155e-01
13: 1.000000645561765e+00
14: 1.000000028771196e+00
15: 1.666666187776715e+00
16: -3.583333074708150e+00
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
Iteration 3
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: 1.027777535146502e+05
 3: 2.972222191231725e+05
 4: -8.263881528669108e+04
 5: 5.555518108303881e+03
 6: -6.636923522614542e-02
 7: 4.677328483600658e-02
 8: 1.991719546327412e-02
 9: -3.148201866790915e-03
10: -2.319389535987426e-02
11: -4.176186143567406e-02
12: 6.726872146719150e-02
13: -5.555525175695851e+03
14: 8.263880834779718e+04
15: -2.972222015189417e+05
16: -1.027777456120210e+05
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
```

Signs of madness...

```
Iteration 4
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: 2.050347140226725e+10
 3: -1.240740057099195e+10
 4: -1.858796490195886e+10
 5: 7.986101364079453e+09
 6: -1.059021715700324e+09
 7: 4.630176289959386e+07
 8: -3.687893612405425e+03
 9: -2.136279835945886e+03
10: -2.968840021291520e+03
11: 4.630204773690500e+07
12: -1.059022490436399e+09
13: 7.986100736580715e+09
14: -1.858796331554353e+10
15: -1.240739964045201e+10
16: 2.050347017082775e+10
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
5th Derivative of sin(x) at x = 3.141592653589793e+00 = -2.136279835945886e+03 (eps = 0.000010)
```

Notice how the results are going beserk with values in the billions in the last iteration.  You have at the least a numerical stability problem, or perhaps you need to review the derivative formula.  Note that even the run with the larger epsilon has a tendency towards large values on the later iterations.

---

#### Using 'official' `derivative()` function

Plugging the derivative function now present in the question into the code above yields even less stable answers in the 4th iteration:

```
Iteration 4
 0: 0.000000000000000e+00
 1: 0.000000000000000e+00
 2: -6.248925477935563e+09
 3: 1.729549900845405e+11
 4: -2.600544559219368e+11
 5: -2.755286326619338e+11
 6: 8.100546069731433e+11
 7: -2.961111189495415e+09
 8: -7.936480686806423e+11
 9: 2.430177384467434e+11
10: 2.389084910067162e+11
11: -6.461168564124718e+10
12: -4.574822745530297e+10
13: -8.923883451146609e+10
14: 7.042030613792160e+10
15: 4.988386306820556e+10
16: -1.793262395787471e+10
17: 0.000000000000000e+00
18: 0.000000000000000e+00
5th Derivative of sin(x) at x = 3.141592653589793e+00 = 2.430177384467434e+11 (eps = 0.000010)
```

I wonder to what extent the appearance of the zeros at array indexes 0, 1, 17, and 18 exacerbate the problem.

Comment: The intention of allocating 2N+9 spaces and having the real value at (N+4) was that the values slowly "corrode" towards the centre, i.e. a range of valid values surrounded by two sections of nonsense values slowly closing in... then at the end of the function the real value makes its escape. (Or that's what I would've liked it to be).<br>Every iteration, the values in positions 0, 1, 17 and 18 are untouched, and are hence 0.

Answer (score 6):

Numerical differentiation is a difficult problem. The key issue is that the finite difference approximation

```
f'(x) =(approx) (f(x+h)-f(x-h)) / (2*h)
```

is a recipe for [cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

This means you have to choose a careful tradeoff between two errors: If h is too large, you will incur a large approximation error in the finite difference. If h is too small, you will incur a large (possibly catastrophic) numerical error. This is illustrated quite nicely in the Wikipedia article on [numerical differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Practical_considerations_using_floating_point_arithmetic). The problems are exacerbated as the order of the derivative increases.

This is why [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) is such a big deal -- in essence, it allows you to compute a precise derivative when all that is given is an algorithm that computes the base function. If the function is simple enough that you can determine the derivative symbolically, then you should probably do that.

If you do need to go with numerical differentiation, there is a lot of numerical finesse you can apply. [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) has a good treatment -- take a look at Section 5.7, which begins on page 186.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky subject. Numerical differentiation is ill-conditioned, and give rise to cancellation and rounding errors. The problem is significantly magnified in your case, where you do repeated differentiation.

You will get much better high order derivative estimations by determining the coefficients for your specific differentiation order N using m points, instead of doing repeated differentiation.

For example, just as you seem to be using the coefficients for the first order derivative:

```
{1, -8, 8, -1} / (12*h)
```

the coefficients for approximating a second order derivative using 5 points are:

```
{-1, 16, -30, 16, -1} / (12*h²)
```

You can solve for the coefficients for a general problem by making a Taylor series expansion around the sample points, finding the linear combination of these expansions that give the wanted derivative.

for the m points {x + n[1]*h, x+n[2]*h, x+n[3]*h, …, x+n[m]*h}, the coefficients (k) estimating the Nth derivative can be calculated by the following system of equations:

```
M*k=b
```

Where M is a m*m matrix:

```
M[i,j] = n[j]^(i-1), i,j = 1..m
```

and

```
b = [0, 0, 0, …, N!/h^N, …, 0, 0, 0],
```

where N! denotes the factorial of N.